# Rails pages apply only after refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have almost completed an practice application in Ruby on Rails. It is kind of like an Q&A but in an simpler manner. I have an link_to root path on the site name on navbar. But the issue is when I was in another page and If I click the home page name, it doesn't show anything but shows data only If i press refresh.

Seeing from the logs, it stops right when the query is executed and no further.. I have deployed the app for the reference @ altur.herokuapp.com

the log during requests,

right after i click the link,

```
    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-11-28 18:36:07 +0530
Processing by QuestionsController#index as HTML
  Question Load (4.0ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" ORDER BY created_at DESC
   (3.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 1]]
  Rendered questions/index.html.erb within layouts/application (14.0ms)
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
Completed 200 OK in 78ms (Views: 69.0ms | ActiveRecord: 8.0ms)
```

After I press the refresh it issues all the GET requests, and the page displays else it is blank..

The same applies for the 'My Questions' link too.. Just the DB queries and no GET requests issued.

```
Processing by QuestionsController#userview as HTML
  Parameters: {"user"=>"1"}
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", "1"]]
  Question Load (3.0ms)  SELECT "questions".* FROM "questions" WHERE "questions"."user_id" = $1  [["user_id", 1]]
   (2.0ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "answers" WHERE "answers"."question_id" = $1  [["question_id", 1]]
  Rendered questions/userview.html.erb within layouts/application (11.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 51ms (Views: 38.0ms | ActiveRecord: 9.0ms)
```

Comment: I had faced the same issue and mine was resolved by placing my javascript code in `$(document).ready(function(){ //Your code comes here})`. Let me know if it helps.

Comment: This worked exactly as expected.. apparently the masonry function was wrapped in '$(window).load' function which when changed to '$(document).ready' it worked..  Have to dig deeper for the cause..

Comment: Glad that it helped .. I had a tough time figuring out the issue :(

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a problem with the js library who assigns the classes to the elements. If you check the html for the homepage after you click the logo link you will notice that:

```
.class masonry
```

is not assigned to the div

```
.blog-grid.
```

And childs has the same problems. You are losting all your classes. I don't know exactly what you are using to create this template. But check for the error when loading the assets or performing the ajax load because you seem to be having a problem there.